# Solve $\log_7 3 = y$; $\log_7 2 = z$; $x = \log_3 2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to figure out they logarithmic equation but it has 3 semicolons and I can not find out what they mean. How do I go about solving it?

I have to solve for $x$.  The answer should be $z/y$.

$\log_7 3 = y$; $\log_7 2 = z$; $x = \log_3 2$

Comment: `The answer should be z/y` The answer to *what* question?

Comment: Answer to x? @dxiv

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon

Comment: @Fawad `x = log3(2)` per OP's post. I see nothing in the posted question that would hint that `z/y` would be a *better* answer.

Comment: $x=\log_3 2=\dfrac{\log_7 2}{\log_7 3}=z/y$ @dxiv

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the 3 equations are equivalent to

$$7^y =3, 7^z=2, \mbox{ and } 3^x=2.$$

Replace the $3$ in the last equation with $7^y$, by dint of the first equation.  And replace the $2$ in the last equation with $7^z$ per the second equation,
and you have

$$(7^y)^x = 7^z$$

or

$$7^{xy} = 7^z.$$

Therefore $xy = z$ and so $x=z/y.$

Answer (score 3):

The semicolons mean "and". So really the problem is asking

> Given $\log_7(3) = y$ and $\log_7(2) = z$ and $\log_3(2) = x$, solve for $x$ in terms of $y $ and $z$.

Hint: Use the change of base formula

$$ \frac{ \log_b(f) }{\log_b(g)} = \log_g(f) .$$

Hint 2: What do you get if you set $b = 7$, $f = 2$ and $g = 3$?

Comment: I still don't get it. When I have to solve for X I have to do the change of base formula for the other 2 equations?

Comment: @Victor Mora Well it is the 7 that is bothering you. So, in order to get rid of it, you need to use the change of base rule